# Is it safe to allow chrome to connect to a local address on TCP Port 8009?

Tags: google-chrome

I use Little Snitch on Mac and I've been getting a lot of notifications that Chrome is trying connect with *.local ports

Here are a few examples:
- On Sep 8, 2018, Google Chrome tried to establish a connection to b3a6605c-dde6-f49b-b478-4afcaa62c7ee.local on TCP port 8009. 
- On Sep 8, 2018, Google Chrome tried to establish a connection to b28972be-1eec-f275-98a7-bbb0c53ff506.local on TCP port 8009. The request was allowed via connection alert.
- On Sep 8, 2018, Google Chrome tried to establish a connection to jolisas-macbook-pro.local on TCP port 8009. The request was allowed via connection alert.
- On Sep 8, 2018, Google Chrome tried to establish a connection to saads-macbook-air.local on TCP port 8009. The request was allowed via connection alert.

Does anybody know why and what these connections would be? Are they safe or should I block them?

Software versions:
MacOs 10.12.6
Google chrome Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Little Snitch 4.1.3

Comment: Chromecast uses port 8009. See [I am looking for the exact list of port numbers used by Chromecast. - Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromecast/G3E2ENn-YZI)

Comment: If I'm not using chromecast, then why would chrome try to establish an outgoing connection on TCP Port 8009?

Comment: This is the common usage of that port. [There are others](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=8009)

Comment: Since Little Snitch is reporting these  as *.local accounts like "b3a6605c-dde6-f49b-b478-4afcaa62c7ee.local" Then are these on an internal network? I'm confused why I'd get chrome trying to do outgoing connections to the .local addresses.